# How to resequence the AUTO_INCREMENT id in MySQL after deleting few records?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a table with 3000 entries.
I am randomly choosing 25 of those to be shifted to another table.
Once this is done, I want the IDs (which are assigned AUTO_INCREMENT and are primary key) in the original table to be in sequence, so that I could perform next iteration.
How should I do it?

Comment: so the entries from the original table are deleted after shifting them?

Comment: Don't.  This question gets asked probably every day here.  The answer is "don't do it".  As an alternative, you *could* create a new table with a new PK that auto-increments and move all of the remaining records to that table.  But... *why*?  What makes you think that the primary key *needs* to always be perfectly sequential?  (Hint: It doesn't)

Comment: You shouldn't.  Primary keys may be foreign keys in another table and need to be changed as well.  If you think you need to do this then you are doing something wrong.

Comment: general rule? you NEVER retroactively change ids. re-using ids is invariably a BAD idea.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with changing the ID's?

Comment: If you have used those id's as foreign keys (or worse as data links) in **any** table then imo, changing the current id's to 'make them sequential' is 'less than useful'. But, what is interesting, is what you are using database relationship id for that requires them to be sequential? This is 'not what they are for'. If you want a sequential 'application id'. imo, Then you create your own and **never** try and use the `database relationship id` for anything to do with meaning in your application. imo, It will end in tears. i.e **keep a separate `sequential id` for use by your applcation.**

Comment: This is a one-way express train to misery and suffering. Recycling or altering `AUTO_INCREMENT` identifiers is **extremely risky** as you can easily expose private, personal information to people who have no business seeing it. If these numbers are used as foreign keys you're going to have to alter those values as well, and then **verify consistency** which can be very time consuming. Turn off your OCD and deal with the holes.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot change the auto_increment value to a value other than the current max value.Auto_Increment is a counter that keeps on incrementing whose value is used for the column for which it is defined.

The only other way to change it to a value just above the current max value is to manually alter the value of the AUTO_INCREMENT Counter to max(value) +1.

So I guess here you have to order the records in ascending by the existing Id after deleting the 25 records and manually set the id value of each record according to an incrementing variable and in the end set the AUTO_INCREMENT count value as the value of variable in the end +1.

Sample :

ALTER TABLE T
SET AUTO_INCREMENT=Some_value;

Though it is advised to leave the AUTO_INCREMENT alone and avoid all this if it's done just for the sake of making ids look great and there is no other probable reason.

Comment: This is 1% of the solution. The other 99% is tracking down all references to these values and adjusting them as well, plus cleaning up the resulting mess that will invariably happen.